# Really impossible to have Gimp 2.8 on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, gimp, pango

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get GIMP 2.8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-gimp-2-8)

For days, I have been trying to find a solution and repositories to install Gimp 2.8 on Ubuntu 11.10. Each time I get this error:

[image]

Tried to update pango via

```
sudo apt-get install pango-graphite
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pango-graphite is already the newest version.
```

Then also tried

```
sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0' for regex 'libgdk-pixbuf2*'
Note, selecting 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev' for regex 'libgdk-pixbuf2*'
Note, selecting 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-doc' for regex 'libgdk-pixbuf2*'
Note, selecting 'libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby' for regex 'libgdk-pixbuf2*'
Note, selecting 'libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby1.8' for regex 'libgdk-pixbuf2*'
Note, selecting 'libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby1.8-dbg' for regex 'libgdk-pixbuf2*'
Note, selecting 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common' for regex 'libgdk-pixbuf2*'
libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby is already the newest version.
libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby1.8 is already the newest version.
libgdk-pixbuf2-ruby1.8-dbg is already the newest version.
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-doc is already the newest version.
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is already the newest version.
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev is already the newest version.
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
```

And still **error** :(.

Please help as I do not want to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 just to have Gimp. Really a mission impossible????

Comment: Have you tried to install Gimp from source?

Comment: There have been horror stories of people completely hos-ing their boxes over-riding dependencies because they want newer gimp.  Just a thought.

Comment: @LnxSlck No source. Just wanted the simpler way

Comment: @aking1012 Well, I guess I'll have to wait...