# How do I get the latest GIMP version available?

Tags: gimp

I understand that there is a new version of the GIMP available, although it appears that the only way of doing this is by compiling from source :P

Is there another way of getting it, or if I have to compile can I do that through the terminal or better still; a GUI?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

### Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 17.10, 18.04 LTS

**You can do this through the Terminal:**

1. Uninstall GIMP

   ```
    sudo apt-get autoremove gimp gimp-plugin-registry
   ```
2. Add the following PPA

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Reinstall the latest GIMP

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gimp
   ```

### Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and above

Steps 1 and 3 are the same. In step 2, use the following PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gimp
```

Comment: Why does GIMP need removed before being upgraded?  I tried adding the PPA and updating without removing it, and it seemed to work fine.  (also, `apt-get autoremove` does not remove configuration files without specifying `--purge`)

Comment: Thanks for this. What will happen when Gimp 2.8 becomes part of the next Ubuntu release, 12.10? What steps should be followed to make everything "clean" again?

Comment: @JohnJ.Camilleri just uninstall GIMP, remove the ppa from your system and install it from ubuntu's official repositories.

Comment: @JohnJ.Camilleri I think that 3rd party PPAs get disabled on upgrade.

Comment: To uninstall Otto's library (from the instructions shown when adding the repo): sudo apt-get install ppa-purge;
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp

Comment: why a simple `sudo apt-get install gimp` doesn't install latest (v2.10.12) but v2.8.22 (released on 8 May 2017)?

Comment: The same for me. I got 2.8.22, but not the latest

Comment: This PPA is not longer updated.

Answer (score 24):

### Ubuntu 14.04 and later

To install the latest stable version of GIMP as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install gimp
```

---

**Notes**

1. If you need an incrementally newer version than the latest stable version (e.g. GIMP 2.10.2 instead of GIMP 2.10.0) install it from  the *edge* channel.

   ```
    sudo snap install gimp --channel=edge
   ```
2. If you need GIMP to have full access to external media (such as USB flash drive, SD/MicroSD card, additional mounted hard drive and so on), run the following command:

   ```
    sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media
   ```

```
$ sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media
$ snap connections gimp
Interface                 Plug                  Slot                              Notes
browser-support           gimp:browser-support  :browser-support                  -
content[gnome-3-38-2004]  gimp:gnome-3-38-2004  gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004   -
content[gtk-2-engines]    gimp:gtk-2-engines    gtk2-common-themes:gtk-2-engines  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     gimp:gtk-3-themes     gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes    -
content[icon-themes]      gimp:icon-themes      gtk-common-themes:icon-themes     -
content[sound-themes]     gimp:sound-themes     gtk-common-themes:sound-themes    -
cups-control              gimp:cups-control     -                                 -
dbus                      -                     gimp:dbus-gimp                    -
desktop                   gimp:desktop          :desktop                          -
desktop-legacy            gimp:desktop-legacy   :desktop-legacy                   -
gsettings                 gimp:gsettings        :gsettings                        -
home                      gimp:home             :home                             -
network                   gimp:network          :network                          -
opengl                    gimp:opengl           :opengl                           -
removable-media           gimp:removable-media  :removable-media                  manual
unity7                    gimp:unity7           :unity7                           -
wayland                   gimp:wayland          :wayland                          -
x11                       gimp:x11              :x11                              -
```

[image]

Comment: What about access to external media (`:removable-media` plug/connector)? Is it classic Snap? Its extremely important for photographs with their flash cards.

Comment: what about plugin-registry or gmic?

Comment: @N0rbert 1. `sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media` 2. *gimp* is not a classic snap.

Comment: @karel Could you please show YAML-manifest as proof of p.1 about removable-media? And edit your answer with this addition.

Comment: FIrst  the last version is 2.10.2 and not 2.10.0
Then I would like to understand why you suggest snapd over flatpak, as GIMP's developers actally do
@karel

Comment: @Polonio *gimp* 2.10.2 is not the latest stable version. It is the latest edge version. To install gimp 2.10.2 type `sudo snap install gimp --edge` The gimp snap package is a native snap package in Ubuntu, so it is easier to install, and it is also updated automatically.

Comment: @karel The current stable release of GIMP is 2.10.2 (2018-05-20).

Comment: what I quoted was the official gimp web site... i don't know...
I Know that snapd version of GIMP is not official, that's could be why it is still at 2.10

Comment: Official in Ubuntu counts for something too, because that means that the package has been vetted by Canonical.

Comment: Ok so the version of Snapd mantained by "Snapcrafters" is the official version of GIMP on Ubuntu? it's what you are saying? Thank you

Comment: @Polonio, Install and use the version of gimp that works best for you, whatever the official status. (But be aware that the newest version might not be tested and accepted [yet] in Ubuntu.)

Comment: @Polonio why do hate snap so much? I don't understand. I use Ubuntu 18.10, and the only way to get "latest stable updated" app is snap. Apt can take many months to deliver those updates.

Comment: In the case of development and IDE packages the latest stable version is sometimes the only version of a package that works for me, and it's good to have the option of installing the latest stable version of a package available in the Ubuntu Software app.

Answer (score 15):

### Ubuntu versions prior to 12.04

Currently there is no method to install Gimp 2.8 on any version below 12.04.

In terms of *is it possible* ...

Unlikely for the following reason:

The dependencies of the latest versions of Gimp require a-lot of the latest underlying libraries that you will not find by default in any version below 12.04. Thus, you will need to recompile and rewrite portions of the code to get it to compile.  The further away you get from 12.04, the larger the change required.

A maintainer of the Gimp package (ppa:matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn) mentions in the description that it needs the latest [Gnome-3 PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu) as well as some other [testing libraries](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu).  Both of these will not install on gnome-2 environments (below 11.10).  Looking at the dependency lists for 12.04 version of Gimp, these are also not available in 11.10.

Will it ever be available in a PPA for versions below 12.04?  Its probably safe to say *unlikely* unless there is an enterprising developer out there who wishes to port this to this.

Until then, [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11946325) has an interesting thread on how to compile from source.

---

Thus - if you definitely want Gimp 2.8 - look to installing 12.04 + one of its many desktop environments.

Comment: Still it is therotically possible :p

Comment: I've got Ubuntu Maverick and I do use GIMP 2.7 since more than one year. I guess the problem is only about GIMP 2.8 and the "not-supported-anymore" system.

Comment: Installing Gimp 2.8 on Ubuntu 10.04 is very do-able since I just did it. The trick is building a newer GTK and a whole bunch of dependencies into /opt/gimp-2.8, using the `prefix=/opt/gimp-2.8` option when compiling *all* dependencies. This will isolate GIMP and all of it's friends in a place where the other applications won't find it.

Answer (score 8):

Fortunatelly the availability of stable GIMP 2.8 also made gimp plugin registry (with the famous save for web plugin) easy to install.

Via http://www.webupd8.org/ :

**GIMP 2.8 stable installation**

If you're upgrading from an older GIMP version please visit the link and pay attention to the 'dist-upgrade' command http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/gimp-28-stable-finally-available-for.html (also if you want to revert to GIMP 2.6.x)

If you're just installing GIMP for the first time on your current system install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

**GIMP Plugin Registry for GIMP 2.8 installation**

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/install-gimp-plugin-registry-for-gimp.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us support this project.

http://portablelinuxapps.org/

I am able to download gimp2.9 and open a file rejected by earlier version of Gimp.
And I am still using ubuntu 10.04 Lucid.

This is really a broken case with Linux systems because you need to upgrade your entire system just to be able to run the latest apps.  I hope this will be solved soon and I hope we support projects like the above.

I am happy with my ubuntu 10.04 and i've have lots of configs here and development files... may have to way until 2016 to upgrade lol!

Answer (score 2):

### Answer as of June 2018, if you want Gimp 2.10

#### For Ubuntu 17.10 and later:

Add the PPA:  https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp
and several packages will be updated/installed from it, nost notably Gimp itself, and gimp-plugin-registry that contains several useful plugins (resynthesize, etc...) that are much easier to install that way. If youa re n <=17.04, this PPA will give you Gimp 2.8.22.

#### For older versions (most notably 16.04):

- The official way: you install a "flatpak" version, which is an application with is own set of dependent libraries. Instructions are available on the [Gimp download page](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/).
- The unofficial way: you install an "AppImage" (which is another way to "containerize" the application). There are several builders for this, one version is [here](https://filebin.net/krwrwb68z3sz6t0x).

Both methods have their restrictions, in particular it can be difficult to add your favorite compiled plugins (script-fu and python plugins are usually OK).

Comment: This PPA is not longer updated.

Comment: @danger89 Try [this one instead](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/gimp). More info [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/ppa-install-gimp-2-10-20-ubuntu-20-04/). Didn't try this myself so I won't add it in the answer.

Comment: Actually Flatpack really worked well on my Linux Mint installation: https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref

Comment: @danger89 You'll find small irritating restrictions with the flatpak version, because it is sandboxed. For instance, Gimp won't share its "most recent" list with other apps. It may also not be able to access mounted media. And adding binary plugins may prove difficult (there are companion flatpaks for some popular plugins).

Answer (score 1):

To get GIMP 2.8 on Lucid 10.04.4 have a look at this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11946325

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 16.10

```
apt install gimp
```

Quite easy now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gimp.GIMP) way of installing GIMP:

```
flatpak install flathub org.gimp.GIMP
```

Once installed you can run GIMP by using this command:

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
```

For me, GIMP would not run as a regular user because of permission errors.  You can find the errors by running GIMP in terminal.  The fix:

```
chmod 755 -R ~/.local/share/flatpak/
chmod 777 -R ~/.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/
```

## OPTIONAL

```
(gimp-2.10:2): IBUS-WARNING **: 11:23:31.019: The owner of /home/user123/.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/config/ibus/bus is not user123!
```

The fix:

```
chown $USER ~/.var/app/org.gimp.GIMP/config/ibus/bus
```

This changes the owner of the bus directory.  $USER in linux is the current logged in user (try echo $USER and see what you get).

Answer (score 0):

### Ubuntu 16.10

In Ubuntu 16.10, you can easily install it from the terminal with the following command:

`sudo apt install gimp`

To upgrade an existing install of gimp, run the following command in the terminal:

`sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y`

If you would like to uninstall gimp but retain settings (if you plan on reinstalling some other time, for example), run the following command in the terminal:

`sudo apt remove gimp`

If you would like to uninstall gimp and remove settings, run the following command in the terminal:

`sudo apt purge gimp`

Answer (score -1):

this PPA works for me and it will give you last  version available 
Note: this may get version still in development too

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
```

also you can go for the other steps down here

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp -y
```

this will display the current version of gimp

```
sudo gimp --version
```

Comment: This PPA is not longer updated.