# Is it safe to install GIMP 2.8 from a PPA?

Tags: ppa, gimp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get GIMP 2.8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-gimp-2-8)

I tried using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp` and got this message:

```
[sudo] password for neil: 
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 CAUTION!

This PPA could break your installed OS if you use Ubuntu series < Precise. There are dependency issues for Oneiric Ocelot (11.10). Only use it if you know what you do!

There are known issues in Precise Pangolin (12.04).

Regards
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/gimp
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

Comment: Not sure, this guy is on 10.10 EDIT: Oh wait the reply says 12.04, sorry. I will try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the problem with oneric not precise.

Just press `Enter`.

Then run `sudo apt-get update`

After that run `sudo apt-get install gimp`

Known issues are ok. Every application has bugs. Isn't it.