# Gimp Terminal install problem

Tags: apt, gimp

```
zarjazc@PL998794-VPCEL22FX:~$ apt-get install gimp
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
zarjazc@PL998794-VPCEL22FX:~$
```

That's what I get when I try to install gimp 2.8 from the website using the terminal code. The software center only has the 2.6 version

Comment: duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/134035/169736

Comment: Please, if someone answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The error that are you getting is because that you have have another package handler or synaptic open, and the other one, because you're not using `sudo`.

To install Gimp 2.8 in Ubuntu 12.04, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: Not the latest.  I don't think

Comment: Umm... raring has 2.8 already. Precise don't, so fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Installing software requires escalated privileges.
`sudo apt-get install gimp`

Comment: `-f` or `--fix-broken` don't install the dependencies. `apt-get install` alone should do that.

Comment: Also, in precise GIMP is version 2.6 while OP wants's 2.8.