# Prevent wine from loading user fonts

Tags: wine, fonts

I'm using PhotoshopCS6 on wine1.7,and this crashes everytime after selecting TypeTool.

I guess some user fonts(*~/.fonts/**) causes crash on wine.

How can I prevent wine from loading user fonts?
Or, is there a way to specify fonts folder to load?

Comment: Try renaming the `.fonts` directory to another name e.g. just `fonts` and see what happens. If nothing changes about the way it crashes, try something else. It may be best to work out the problem before the solution. Also, running wine inside a virtual desktop (go to wine config) may work better (not always, but sometimes). Try editing the Photoshop settings to see if anything improves. If you get fed yp with Photoshop, try GIMP 2.8 instead - [instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-gimp-2-8)

Comment: Thanks to quick reply. When I tried that, I could type some words without crash, so i guessed my user fonts caused that. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are patient and have nothing to do for the next decade, you could test each font (or group of fonts) to see if it the cause. You could also install the fonts as a system font (in `usr/share/font` instead of `~/.font` - but a root password is required) - but it is just a font causing the problem, this will make things worse. So I would either: try and live without the fonts in `.font`; re-enable `.font` only when not using Photoshop;  or just try GIMP - which is free and should not blow up anything anyway.

Comment: I can't agree more with you.

Renaming ~/.fonts only when use Photoshop on wine.

I think that is better way to use Photoshop on wine for now.
P.S. I'm using Photoshop on VMWare/Virtualbox, and GIMP.

Comment: For now I think that is the better way to launch PhotoshopCS6 on wine like

`mv $HOME/.fonts $HOME/.fonts.bak; env WINEPREFIX="/home/iaarchiver/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/iaarchiver/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/iaarchiver/Start\ Menu/Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS6\ Extended.lnk; mv $HOME/.fonts.bak $HOME/.fonts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your question is answered anyway, but I'll add this anyway. This is based on a similar bash script I use for opening Audacity with wine *(I have the Linux version, but that does not work with some of the plugins)*.

```
#!/bin/bash
Red="\033[1;31m"
clear="\033[1m\033[0m"
mv /home/iaarchiver/.fonts /home/iaarchiver/.fonts.moved
echo -e "$Red Moved fonts directory - starting Photoshop."
wine start /unix '/home/iaarchiver/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Photoshop/Photoshop.exe'
echo -e  "Photoshop Exited - Returning fonts directory. $clear"
mv /home/iaarchiver/.fonts.moved /home/iaarchiver/.fonts
echo "Goodbye!"
```

If you save this and run it in terminal, it should:

- Move the `.font` file to `.font.moved`
- tell you that it is starting Photoshop (in a red colour).
- Start Photoshop *(**WILL** need a different command from this)*
- Tell you photoshop has closed and return the fonts directory.

I have not tested this - but it should work - You will need to change the filename locations as I only guessed them from your comments.

N.B. The $Red and $clear are not necessary, but were in my original script so I left them in

Comment: I'm simply using photoshopcs6.sh:
`#!/bin/bash
mv $HOME/.fonts $HOME/.fonts.moved && 
env WINEPREFIX="/home/iaarchiver/.wine" wine ... &&
mv $HOME/.fonts.moved $HOME/.fonts`
No crash for now, thanks wilf!