# How to install Resynthesizer in gimp?

Tags: gimp

I dont know how to install Resynthesizer in gimp.I want Resynthesizer for editing my images.Anyone please help

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**For GIMP <= 2.8** the "Resynthesizer" plugin together with other scripts and tools (including the brilliant tool "[Heal Selection](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/how-can-i-remove-text-from-a-background)") can easily be installed with the package [gimp-plugin-registry](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp-plugin-registry)

From the shell:

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-plugin-registry
```

---

**For Gimp >= 2.10** the plugin-registry and with it the resynthesizer and heal-selection plugins may not (yet) be available. Until we have access to these tools again we need to put the plugins

- resynthesizer
- resynthesizer_gui
- plugin-heal-selection.py

to any of the defined plugin folders. I recommend `~/.config/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins` in our HOME.

We can get these either from compiling the source from the [project's home page](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer) or from downloading [an Ubuntu DEB file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gimp-plugin-registry) a release of the plugin-registry for GIMP 2.8 matching our architecture to extract above files. I tested these to still work on GIMP 2.10.6.

Comment: No longer included in the package as of May 09 '14; at least not in version 3.5.4-1 for Ubuntu 12.04. Hope this saves other users some time.

Comment: Still there in later releases. You may have to upgrade Gimp to 2.8 to get it working then. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-the-latest-gimp-version-available

Comment: This no longer seems to work in GIMP 2.8 on Ubuntu 18. This package does not contain the Resynthesizer plugin.

Comment: @Cerin: sorry to hear you have issues. Resynthesizer and heal selection are still provided with the default gimp-plugin-registry package for 18.04 ([see here for a list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/gimp-plugin-registry/filelist)). Did you add a ppa for these packages? You may have to install it manually, as outlined above.

Comment: @Takkat I was incorrect. I initially tried to install the precompiled version linked from the github repo, but for some reason that's a 32-bit version that doesn't work on any modern 64-bit system. However, if that's installed, it also prevents the package from working, since the `~/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins` directory overrides the package's. Once I deleted my local plug-ins folder, then the package plugins worked.

Comment: Got it worked by following,
https://askubuntu.com/a/377330/1384856
(Gimp - 2.10.28) Make sure the folder plugins are copied to, is configured in Gimp.
Check: Edit > Preferences > Folders > Plug-ins

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone used flatpak to install the lateset GIMP (2.10.20 as of this writing), I ran the command `flatpak search org.gimp.GIMP` and noticed the following package available:

org.gimp.GIMP.Plugin.Resynthesizer

Seeing that, I ran `flatpak install org.gimp.GIMP.Plugin.Resynthesizer`, opened up GIMP, and the new filters were available and worked as expected.

you can also search for all plugins avalible to install using flatpak:

```
flatpak search org.gimp.GIMP.plugin
```

Comment: flatpak search GIMP
No matches found

Comment: Worked! You saved my day.

Comment: That plugin got integrated only when i installed the latter option of the available packatge runtimes i.e. version `x86_64/2-40`

Comment: That worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04: I had Gimp installed with Snap so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it with Flatpak, did exactly what you suggested, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

On **Ubuntu 20.04** and later, with GIMP 2.10.18 (latest as of today), the Resynthesizer plugin is again included in the `gimp-plugin-registry` package. Install it with:

```
sudo apt install gimp-plugin-registry
```

However, probably due to the fact that Resynthesizer 2.x still relies on Python 2.x and this is no longer supported on Ubuntu, only the core plugin "Resynthesizer" is included and not the eight more specialized plugins like "Heal Selection", because these eight are implemented as Python scripts. Resynthesizer 3.0 for GIMP 3, once released, will use Python 3.x ([source](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer/wiki/Resynthesizer-and-GIMP-version-3#changes-in-the-deprecations-branch)), and then we can expect its Python scripts to again come as part of this package.

### How to cope without the Python-based plugins

In practice, only having the Resynthesizer core plugin available does not limit our options, it just complicates how to achieve what we want:

> **[Filter >] Map > Resynthesize...**
>
> […] The hardest to understand, but the most powerful. […] But you must know specific steps to get one of the many effects. That's what the other plugins do automatically, they "know" the steps. The other plugins can all be replicated by specific steps using the control panel plugin.
>
> ([source](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer/wiki/Quick-user%27s-guide-to-the-Resynthesizer-plugins-for-GIMP#mapresynthesize))

For example, here are the **steps to remove an object with Resynthesizer**:

1. **Open the image to work on.** If possible, work on a cropped version of a very large image, as the plugin may otherwise crash.
2. In the image to work on, **select the area to overwrite**. All pixels in the selection will be replaced with best-fitting pixels given the surrounding texture, and there will be no seams at the edge of the selection.
3. **Open another image** to provide the input texture. This should be a copy of the image you work on.
4. In the texture input image, **select all pixels that should be used to calculate the texture** for replacing the pixels you don't want in the image you work on. Typically that would be the full picture except  the pixels you want replaced. Means, typically this and your other selection would not have any pixels in common, and together select the whole image.
5. Open **"Filter → Map → Resynthesizer"** from the image you work on. Select the texture input image in the form, and execute the Resynthesizer, leaving all other options at their default values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link: https://web.archive.org/web/20180225174428/http://registry.gimp.org/node/27986

Basically you download the file and extract it, after that you copy it into your gimp plug-ins folder.

Folder location: Go to your home folder, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>, search for `.gimp2.x` folder (x is  number of your gimp version) then search for plug-ins folder.

Comment: Is the link still alive? I can't reach anything by this address...

Comment: link is dead. Please see the [git repo](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer). There are instructions on how to get things working.

Comment: "The registry is dead!" Please update your answer. Don't simply add a comment. You're allowed to edit your own answers. Also, the git instructions don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked - `flatpak install flathub org.gimp.GIMP.Plugin.Resynthesizer`

Comment: did not work for me till i added the flathub - not sure why; so how is this a duplicate?