# Error when using Resynthesizer plugin in Gimp 2.8.10

Tags: 14.04, python, plugins, gimp

I'm trying to make Resynthesizer plug-in work in Gimp 2.8.10 under Ubuntu 14.04 TLS but I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 699, in response
    dialog.res = run_script(params)
  File "/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 361, in run_script
    return apply(function, params)
  File "/home/olivier/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/plugin-heal-selection.py", line 148, in heal_selection
    pdb.plug_in_resynthesizer(timg, tdrawable, 0,0, useBorder, work_drawable.ID, -1, -1, 0.0, 0.117, 16, 500)
error: procedure not found
```

I downloaded the plugin here: http://registry.gimp.org/node/27986, extracted all in `/home/olivier/.gimp-2.8/plug-ins/`

Then make all files in this folder read, write, execute.

But I get this error. I have no more ideas.

A same question was launched in November last year and was closed because it was a bug report issue. Is it still the same one year later?

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377307/how-to-install-resynthesizer-in-gimp it should work without issue.

Comment: Start by installing the plug-in on this page:
[https://linuxappfinder.com/package/gimp-resynthesizer](https://linuxappfinder.com/package/gimp-resynthesizer)

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, this is v1.0, while v2.0 is already available (not as a build though).

You can fetch source code from https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer and build it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error as you. After removing the current non working plugin files, look up "gimp-plugin-registry" in the ubuntu software center. After I installed this the heal selection filter was available and worked.