# Heal selection tool does not show

Tags: graphics, snap, plugins, gimp, tools

I have installed the gimp resynthesizer plugging and extracted it under the plug-ins folder but heal selection tool does not show under filters>enhance. How do i fix this? I'm using gimp 2.10 and installed with snap package.

Comment: Probably 2.10, not 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resynthesizer plugin requires Python V2 support (the core component is called from two Python scripts). But since Ubuntu 20.04 the Python support is not include in he distributed Gimp because Python v2 is deprecated.

In addition it is not clear that the external `resynthesize` module can access libraries in the SNAP.

IMHO your best solution is to use the [Gimp distributed as a flatpak](https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/org.gimp.GIMP) by the [Gimp project](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) which:

- is more up-to-date than Ubuntu snaps
- comes with its built-in Python v2 support
- and has are companion flatpaks for popular plugins ([resynthesize](https://askubuntu.com/a/1268279/548230) and GMIC among others).

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted, then (check mark near the upvote/downvote buttons)