# Docking floating text options window in GIMP 2.8.10?

Tags: gimp

Regarding on-canvas text editing in the GIMP:  is there any way to dock, move, or eliminate the floating text options window?  I use the text tool for captioning and labeling, and it gets in the way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Even though GIMP comes preinstalled with Ubuntu, this is not an Ubuntu-related problem and therefore I'd consider it off topic. This question is more fit in a GIMP forum.

Comment: @the_Seppi Considering we even support using third party apps on Ubuntu, and that most apps officially provided on Ubuntu are shared with numerous other OSes, I think this is fully on-topic. Once a question about GIMP becomes sufficiently advanced that it's a question about *art* rather than about *how to use a program*, it would make sense to consider it off-topic. Until then, it seems to be this falls well within [the topics established as okay to ask about here](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think this was a feature of Gimp 2.6, try [installing Gimp 2.8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-the-latest-gimp-version-available) which doesn't have a 'floating text window'

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in GIMP 2.8.x.

With more and more tools having such on-canvas dialogs in the current development version, there might be more need to move them in some way, but so far there hasn't been much discussion about this among the GIMP developers.