# GIMP 2.10 Doesn't Have Permission To Access a USB Drive. Why? How to Resolve? (18.04)

Tags: usb, permissions, snap, gimp

GIMP 2.10 (snap version) doesn't allow me to open the `/media` directory, so I'm **unable to access my external USB drive**. I get the following **error message**:

[image]

I get the **same error** message if I try and open an image file in **Nautilus** from the USB drive **by Right-Click image file > Open with GIMP**

I installed GIMP 2.10 with snap:

```
sudo snap install gimp
```

There's obviously something I'm missing in terms of configuration, but I can't find a similar question posted yet.

**Update**:

I was pointed to the solution to resolve the problem:
[How do I get the latest GIMP version available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-the-latest-gimp-version-available/1046854#1046854)

You need to **give the snap GIMP package explicit permission to access external media** once installed:

```
sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media
```

Why we have to do this extra step, is alluded to by N0rbert:

[How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034030/how-to-get-access-to-usb-storage-from-the-application-installed-as-snap/1034065#1034065)

"...if the application does not have auto-connect of removable-media we need to connect it manually"

My question is why would an application package be created without the ability to access external media by default?

Comment: The main problem here is a Snap, not latest version of GIMP. See my answer on [How to get access to USB-storage from the application installed as Snap?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034065/66509).

Comment: Thank You. This command works with Gimp, Krita, Filezilla and other apps.Thank You Very Much. Best command ever !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes the packager of the snap package gives the snap package explicit permission to access external media and sometimes the packager does not, so the decision to give the snap package explicit permission to access external media is left to the user. Since there's no overriding policy, the decision to enable removable media support is up to the packager of the snap package and after that it's up to the user.

I have observed that snap packages are generally less reliable than apt packages which means that I often install a snap package, and then I have to uninstall it because it didn't work properly. So I guess that not enabling removable media support on some snap packages adds another layer of security to the snap package that the packager thought it needed.

If you need GIMP to have full access to external media (such as USB flash drive, SD/MicroSD card, additional mounted hard drive and so on), run the following command:

```
sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media
```

```
$ sudo snap connect gimp:removable-media
$ snap connections gimp
Interface                 Plug                  Slot                              Notes
browser-support           gimp:browser-support  :browser-support                  -
content[gnome-3-38-2004]  gimp:gnome-3-38-2004  gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004   -
content[gtk-2-engines]    gimp:gtk-2-engines    gtk2-common-themes:gtk-2-engines  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     gimp:gtk-3-themes     gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes    -
content[icon-themes]      gimp:icon-themes      gtk-common-themes:icon-themes     -
content[sound-themes]     gimp:sound-themes     gtk-common-themes:sound-themes    -
cups-control              gimp:cups-control     -                                 -
dbus                      -                     gimp:dbus-gimp                    -
desktop                   gimp:desktop          :desktop                          -
desktop-legacy            gimp:desktop-legacy   :desktop-legacy                   -
gsettings                 gimp:gsettings        :gsettings                        -
home                      gimp:home             :home                             -
network                   gimp:network          :network                          -
opengl                    gimp:opengl           :opengl                           -
removable-media           gimp:removable-media  :removable-media                  manual
unity7                    gimp:unity7           :unity7                           -
wayland                   gimp:wayland          :wayland                          -
x11                       gimp:x11              :x11                              -
```

There is also a GUI way to give a snap application access to removable media from the Software app. Snap packages that allow access to removable media will display a Permissions button in the Software app after they are installed.

[image]

Click the permissions button and then toggle the *Read/write files on removable storage devices* slider from Off to On as shown in the above screenshot.

Comment: Thanks karel, but why does snap treat packages differently to apt... they both need sudo to perform, so if apt trusts the package installed by sudo why doesn't snap?

Comment: I have observed that snap packages are generally less reliable than apt packages which means that I often install a snap package and then uninstall it because it didn't work properly. So I guess that not enabling removable media support on some snap packages adds another layer of security to the snap package that the packager thought it needed.

Comment: Interesting, that's good to know... can you please add that to your answer and that should do it. Thanks again

Comment: I had the same issue with a different package from gimp, and the snap thing didn't work in my case (no removable-media plug for that package). But your second paragraph helped: it prompted me to uninstall and then install the apt-get way instead, after which everything worked fine!