# How can I grant GIMP access to all the contents of my home folder?

Tags: snap, gimp

I have installed GIMP through snap, and it works well. However, I need to access with it to some folders and files that are not in my default `/home/user` paths (i.e. `~/Desktop`, `~/Music` and so on), some of which are also hidden. Some research (e.g. [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054893/gimp-2-10-doesnt-have-permission-to-access-a-usb-drive-why-how-to-resolve-1), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238211/how-to-make-snaps-access-hidden-files-and-folders-in-home)) suggested me that I have to run something like `sudo snap connect gimp:personal-files`, but if I do so I get an error:

```
user@pc:~$ sudo snap connect gimp:personal-files
error: snap "gimp" has no plug named "personal-files"
```

How can I grant GIMP access to all the contents of my home folder?

Comment: What about this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1158109/631600 ?

Comment: Any particular reason why you installed the snap rather than the regular package(s)?

Comment: @pLumo I had already tried it, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Siep Just because I prefer to get the updates as soon as possible.