# Guidance Needed-Command line in terminal to install Gimp 2.10.6 from flatpakref

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gimp, flatpak

Try as I might, I cannot come up with a terminal command that will install Gimp 2.10.6 from the `flatpak` package.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install computer/home/paul/downloads/org.gimp.gimp.flatpackref
```

& I get the error message:

```
cannot find package 'home/paul/downloads/org.gimp.gimp.flatpakref
```

So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install computer/home/paul/downloads/org.gimp.gimp.flatpackref  --directory
```

& I get:

```
confused with options presented with --directory
```

So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install computer/home/paul/downloads/org.gimp.gimp.flatpackref
 --directory /home/paul/cache/org.gimp.gimp.flatpakref
```

I tried each command several times with different derivations and I got the error messages every time. Terminal either says I haven't specified the target, or if I do, it says

```
confused by options presented with --directory.
```

I need someone to give me a command line prompt that will install the Linux gimp 2.10.6 package @ `home/paul/` applications or `home/paul/cache`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the latest GIMP version available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-the-latest-gimp-version-available)

Answer (score 2):

You install the flatpak Gimp using flatpak itself, not Apt. As far as I can tell:

- Install flatpak:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install flatpak
  ```
- Add the flatpak repo (could already be set):

  ```
  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
  ```
- Install Gimp:

  ```
  flatpak install flathub org.gimp.GIMP
  ```
- Run Gimp:

  ```
  flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
  ```

(from the current Howtos, but installing flatpak Gimp on my 16.04 was a no-brainer)

You will also update Gimp the same way, possibly with just a:

```
flatpak update
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Xenoid for your information.  I successfully executed several of the commands [you gave me](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074727/527764) and was able to install flatpak.

Then I did another search and found [this article on itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/gimp-2-10-release) which has a real gold mine of advice about how to load Gimp 2.10 into Ubuntu.  I used the following instructions, and terminal loaded Gimp right up!  :-)

> #### Method 1: Installing GIMP 2.10 via Snap Packages
>
> You can use Snap for installing GIMP 2.10. If you are using Ubuntu, you are good. For other Linux distributions, please make sure that you have Snap support enabled.
>
> With Snap installed, all you have to do is to use the Snap command:
>
> ```
> snap install gimp
> ```
>
> That’s it. GIMP 2.10.x will be installed.

This is what I did and it worked like a charm!  Problem fixed!